# Where do we get other users stories and how to import that in our app in wit.ai?

Tags: wit.ai

I have created a new app in wit.ai. I created new stories for that app with intent and replies using 'Bot sends'. I'm using node.js. It works normally as expected. There is no issues with this.

What I want to know is 
1. Where do we get the other users stories.
2. How do we import that stories in our existing app?

We can import the zip file of an existing app, while creating a new app. But how do we import in our app which is already created? All wit.ai related articles mention about reducing training time by using stories of other users, but I'm not able to find such stories.

Thanks.